# What does ～と見てよい/～と見ていい mean? How did it have its meaning?

Tags: words, phrases

I found these sentences using [SPACEALC](http://www.alc.co.jp/):

The content in parentheses and bolding are my own:

> 1. まず勝ち試合**と見ていい**が、成り行き任せでは駄目です。
>      You'll probably win the game, but that's not automatic.
> 2. ゴドフリィ・ノートンはこの件に深く関与している**と見ていい****だろう**。
>      "This Godfrey Norton was evidently an important factor in the matter.
> 3. ＜that以下＞は間違いない**と見てよい**。
>      It appears certain that
> 4. 例えば、「おはようございます」と言ってみて相手の外国人が「はあ？」と不思議そうな顔を見せたら、日本語を話せない**と見てよい**。
>      If, for example, you say, "Ohayo gozaimasu," and they look at you perplexed and utter, "HUH?", it's pretty good bet that they don't (speak Japanese).
> 5. 勇気は人間の資質の中で最も重要なもの**と見てよい**。なぜならそれは他のすべての資質を保証する資質だからだ。
>      Courage is rightly esteemed the first of human qualities, because it is the quality which guarantees all others.

1. First I would like to draw attention to sentences 1 through 4. I gathered that と見てよい means something along the lines of "appear to be"
2. Then consider sentences 2 and 5 where it seems to have the senses of "evident" and "rightly esteemed" which is like my previous conclusion of "appear to be" except **much** stronger.
3. Then consider sentence 2 that ends in だろう, which weakens the assertion.

This makes me a little confused.

**(Question)** What does と見ていい・よい mean? 
 How does this link back to what we know of て-form + いい?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

～と見ていい basically means "safe to assume" or "safe to say" - this is why the association with an assumption is so strong. But it can also be an analogy or a more restatement of one thing as another, as in the cases of #2 and #5. There, it isn't an assumption, per se; rather it is a statement of a general sentiment. It becomes uncertain when followed by ～だろう as normal.

More generally, AをBと見る is just "to view A as B". と is a normal quoting particle, and いい is used for acceptability as usual. I think the tricky bit here is that 見る is being used in a way we aren't as used to.

So really, it isn't any more than the sum of it's parts. The meaning is surprisingly straightforward. The literal approximation suggested in [your comment](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/9564/384#comment20025_9569), is `viewing __ as ～ is acceptable.` works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that it means something like: though there is not enough evidence/proof/guarantee/... of a fact/matter/... , it is safe to make the assumption that the fact/matter/... is true.

It is a very strong assumption.

Comment: So if I try to derive it from ~見て+いい, would it be "seeing it as ~ is acceptable(good)" ?

Comment: @Flaw I think so.