# と考えていい ending sentence meaning?

Tags: grammar

In Season 2, Episode 3 of Shingeki no Kyojin at 12:30, I encountered this sentence:

```
その表層は硬化した皮膚で形成されていると考えていい
```

I understand its meaning literally is: "I think that this surface is constructed by harden skin."

But I searched everywhere and can't find と考えていい used anywhere.
What is the meaning of adding ていい? is it a little redundant? 
Thank you.

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/9564/7810

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would translate と考えていい as: "You can think of it as...". It's like a shorter form of 〜てもいい.

Your given sentence would be something like:

```
"You can think of that surface as being molded/formed from hardened skin."
```

Comment: The questioned portion is right but wrong parsing. It's ［その表層～されている］と考えていい.

Comment: Ah yeah that makes sense. I'll remove that part, thanks. Speaking of which, I tried to look for the aforementioned quote at episode 3 (I assume season 1?) @ 12:30 but was unable to locate it.

Comment: sorry for the unclear marking. It is at 12:04, episode 3, season 2. 
Btw, thank your very much for ur answer!